# 2008 Jeep Wrangler ticking when idling and gets faster as rpms go up

Tags: engine, oil, noise, jeep

My Jeep wrangler 3.8L V6 has a ticking noise while idling and it gets faster as the rpms go up. It started happening and I checked the engine oil and it was empty I filled it right up after.

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?

Comment: i just want to know what the problem could be?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the question you put in your comment.

Comment: My JK did that, they all burn a bit of oil, it was valvetrain noise and if you don't keep an eye on your oil, that noise will come and go and ruin your engine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you ran it without oil you can destroy your engine. From rod knock,  to a  seized up engine. Or if it was really low. You could have just had a lifter noise(tap noise). You either loss your oil by a leak or burning the oil internally or just plan lack of maintenance.